# Can "maybe" be used in this way?

Tags: word-usage

If an acquaintance of mine asks me to visit their house, can I say "Tomorrow, maybe?" to say "Maybe I can come tomorrow." in short? I think I've seen this usage before, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Yes, in a casual context, this is fine.

Comment: No problems...it is fine.